# Runtime Normal Map Import in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, normals

For my project, I need to create materials at run time. When I create material, Normal map has no effect. I tried the two solutions about this but they did not work for me. Is something has changed about this in Unity 5 ?

**The Links I checked :**

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/801670/runtime-loading-normal-texture.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47121/runtime-normal-map-import.html

**P.S:** The weird thing is when I switch to "Scene View" inside Unity, If I expand material tab from "Inspector" Normal Map is being applied to the object.

**My Code:**

```
            ....
Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard (Specular setup)"));
mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", colortex);

normaltex = getNormalTexture(Texture2D source);
mat.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normaltex);
mat.SetFloat("_Glossiness", 0.1f);
mat.SetFloat("_BumpScale", 1.0f);

            ....             

public static Texture2D getNormalTexture(Texture2D source)
{
    Texture2D normalTexture = new Texture2D(source.width, source.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);
    Color theColour = new Color();
    for (int x = 0; x < source.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < source.height; y++)
        {
            theColour.r = 0;
            theColour.g = source.GetPixel(x, y).g;
            theColour.b = 0;
            theColour.a = source.GetPixel(x, y).r;
            normalTexture.SetPixel(x, y, theColour);
        }
    }
    normalTexture.Apply();
    return normalTexture;
 }
```

Comment: How are you accessing `mat`? I'm imagining scenarios where you might be editing the wrong material instance. If you haven't, you should also double check that your shader expects a texture variable named `_BumpMap`.

Comment: @rutter I create new material using Shader.Find() function. (I updated my code above). Normal map and Color Texture is added to correct place. However Normal-map is activating when I select the object and expand the material component from "Inspector" in the unity editor at Scene View. The problem is unity save normal-texture in a different format called DXTnm and it does not recognise my texture unless I click it on the editor. When I click the material it probably convert normal texture to correct format.

Answer (score 0):

At least with Unity 4.x you had to modify the shader to display runtime normal maps correctly. Just needed to remove UnpackNormal() from the code.

Technical details:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/creating-runtime-normal-maps-using-rendertotexture.135841/#post-924587

Builtin shader sources can be downloaded from:
http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive